# CakePHP File API

Tags: php, file, cakephp

I'm currently developing a form to upload a file to the server I'm working on. I can successfully upload a file to one of my app's folder without issue. What I want to do next is to read the file that was uploaded and add its info to a data base. To do this I'm using `CakePHP`'s file `API`, but I can't get the constructor to work. Here is my code

```
<?php
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
App::uses( 'String', 'Utility');
App::uses( 'File', 'Utility');

class UploadComponent extends Component{
    public $max_files = 1;
    public $filePath;


    public function upload($data = null){

        if( !empty( $data ) ){
            if(count ($data) > $this->max_files){
                throw new NotFoundException("Error procesando el pedido, el número máximo de archivos aceptados es {$this->max_files}", 1);
            }
            foreach($data AS $file){
                $filename = $file['name'];
                $file_tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
                $dir = WWW_ROOT.'files'.DS.'uploads';
                $allowed = array('txt');
                if( !in_array( substr( strrchr( $filename, '.'), 1), $allowed)){
                    throw new NotFoundException("Error procesando el pedido", 1);
                }elseif(is_uploaded_file( $file_tmp_name)){
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $dir.DS.String::uuid().$filename);
                    $filePath = $dir.DS.String::uuid().$filename;
                    echo gettype($filePath);
                    $import = new File($filePath); //this line throws an error

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm confused as the `API` says that it receives a path in form of a `string`, which `$filePath` is, but it is saying that it's receiving an array. Any idea on how to make it work? 
These are the errors the framework shows:

dirname() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE\Cake\Utility\File.php, line 87]

is_dir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given [CORE\Cake\Utility\File.php, line 88]

basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE\Cake\Utility\File.php, line 89]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this errors in your code. Correct this and see if it solves the problem.

```
 move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $dir.DS.String::uuid().$filename);
 $filePath = $dir.DS.String::uuid().$filename;
```

each time you call `String::uuid()` it gives you random uuid. You wont have filePath where you moved file.

It should be

```
 $filePath = $dir.DS.String::uuid().$filename;
 move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $filePath);
```

Also you can use `debug()` function to see what value a variable has.

```
debug($filePath);
```